# R-3 not defined because of singularities

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm now currently learning regression analysis and R-code.
This is the first time I encounter this problem and I've referred to another post regarding this problem.
However, I still cant find my problem.

````
#Multiple with all interaction term
Multi.interact.reg<-lm(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+I(X1*X2)+I(X1*X3)+I(X1*X4)+I(X1*X5)+I(X1*X6)+I(X2*X3)+I(X2*X4)+I(X2*X5)+I(X2*X6)+I(X3*X4)+I(X3*X5)+I(X3*X6)+I(X4*X5)+I(X4*X6)+I(X5*X6),data = assignment.data)```
summary(Multi.interact.reg)
Multi.interact.anova<-anova(Multi.interact.reg)
Multi.interact.anova
````

Then, I get this bunch of result and it appeared 3 not defined because of singularities

```
Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + I(X1 * X2) + I(X1 * 
    X3) + I(X1 * X4) + I(X1 * X5) + I(X1 * X6) + I(X2 * X3) + 
    I(X2 * X4) + I(X2 * X5) + I(X2 * X6) + I(X3 * X4) + I(X3 * 
    X5) + I(X3 * X6) + I(X4 * X5) + I(X4 * X6) + I(X5 * X6), 
    data = assignment.data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-36.471  -4.328  -0.738   3.290  70.526 

Coefficients: (3 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -5.039e+04  1.724e+04  -2.922  0.00367 ** 
X1           6.777e+00  4.415e+00   1.535  0.12560    
X2           3.325e+02  7.528e+02   0.442  0.65895    
X3           8.762e+00  4.172e+00   2.100  0.03634 *  
X4           5.420e+03  4.136e+03   1.311  0.19077    
X5           9.939e+02  1.631e+02   6.092 2.65e-09 ***
X6           9.853e+01  1.178e+02   0.837  0.40337    
I(X1 * X2)   1.042e-01  1.260e-01   0.827  0.40879    
I(X1 * X3)  -8.575e-04  1.352e-03  -0.634  0.52619    
I(X1 * X4)  -3.882e-01  6.075e-01  -0.639  0.52321    
I(X1 * X5)          NA         NA      NA       NA    
I(X1 * X6)          NA         NA      NA       NA    
I(X2 * X3)   8.612e-06  7.877e-05   0.109  0.91300    
I(X2 * X4)   9.445e-03  1.384e-02   0.682  0.49552    
I(X2 * X5)  -2.897e+00  4.374e+00  -0.662  0.50819    
I(X2 * X6)  -3.869e+00  5.762e+00  -0.671  0.50233    
I(X3 * X4)  -1.687e-03  3.852e-04  -4.378 1.54e-05 ***
I(X3 * X5)  -2.229e-01  4.396e-02  -5.072 6.08e-07 ***
I(X3 * X6)  -1.212e-02  2.702e-02  -0.449  0.65393    
I(X4 * X5)  -1.071e+02  2.150e+01  -4.981 9.49e-07 ***
I(X4 * X6)  -1.615e+01  3.119e+01  -0.518  0.60474    
I(X5 * X6)          NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.903 on 395 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6773,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6626 
F-statistic: 46.06 on 18 and 395 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16


Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Y
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
X1           1    585     585   9.3699 0.0023565 ** 
X2           1   3441    3441  55.0854 7.148e-13 ***
X3           1  34857   34857 558.0314 < 2.2e-16 ***
X4           1   3576    3576  57.2444 2.733e-13 ***
X5           1   2065    2065  33.0577 1.793e-08 ***
X6           1      5       5   0.0821 0.7745688    
I(X1 * X2)   1    217     217   3.4746 0.0630583 .  
I(X1 * X3)   1      0       0   0.0016 0.9680901    
I(X1 * X4)   1      4       4   0.0704 0.7908357    
I(X2 * X3)   1    801     801  12.8267 0.0003843 ***
I(X2 * X4)   1     94      94   1.5072 0.2202955    
I(X2 * X5)   1      1       1   0.0101 0.9198052    
I(X2 * X6)   1      1       1   0.0085 0.9265045    
I(X3 * X4)   1   3805    3805  60.9172 5.390e-14 ***
I(X3 * X5)   1    481     481   7.6932 0.0058058 ** 
I(X3 * X6)   1    297     297   4.7533 0.0298321 *  
I(X4 * X5)   1   1542    1542  24.6828 1.008e-06 ***
I(X4 * X6)   1     17      17   0.2683 0.6047441    
Residuals  395  24673      62                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

[dput(head(assignment.data, 10))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAGQU.png)

Thank you very much for anyone that solve my problem.

Comment: Could you please share `dput(head(assignment.data, 10))`?, this can happen when the column has more zeros than ones

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez I'll incl in my question