# R, Coefficient:3 not defined because of singularities

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I'm now currently learning regression analysis and R-code.
This is the first time I encounter this problem and I've referred to another post regarding this problem.
However, I still cant find my problem.
Sorry for post twice.

````
#Multiple with all interaction term
Multi.interact.reg<-lm(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+I(X1*X2)+I(X1*X3)+I(X1*X4)+I(X1*X5)+I(X1*X6)+I(X2*X3)+I(X2*X4)+I(X2*X5)+I(X2*X6)+I(X3*X4)+I(X3*X5)+I(X3*X6)+I(X4*X5)+I(X4*X6)+I(X5*X6),data = assignment.data)```
summary(Multi.interact.reg)
Multi.interact.anova<-anova(Multi.interact.reg)
Multi.interact.anova
````

Then, I get this bunch of result and it appeared 3 not defined because of singularities

```
Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + I(X1 * X2) + I(X1 * 
    X3) + I(X1 * X4) + I(X1 * X5) + I(X1 * X6) + I(X2 * X3) + 
    I(X2 * X4) + I(X2 * X5) + I(X2 * X6) + I(X3 * X4) + I(X3 * 
    X5) + I(X3 * X6) + I(X4 * X5) + I(X4 * X6) + I(X5 * X6), 
    data = assignment.data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-36.471  -4.328  -0.738   3.290  70.526 

Coefficients: (3 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -5.039e+04  1.724e+04  -2.922  0.00367 ** 
X1           6.777e+00  4.415e+00   1.535  0.12560    
X2           3.325e+02  7.528e+02   0.442  0.65895    
X3           8.762e+00  4.172e+00   2.100  0.03634 *  
X4           5.420e+03  4.136e+03   1.311  0.19077    
X5           9.939e+02  1.631e+02   6.092 2.65e-09 ***
X6           9.853e+01  1.178e+02   0.837  0.40337    
I(X1 * X2)   1.042e-01  1.260e-01   0.827  0.40879    
I(X1 * X3)  -8.575e-04  1.352e-03  -0.634  0.52619    
I(X1 * X4)  -3.882e-01  6.075e-01  -0.639  0.52321    
I(X1 * X5)          NA         NA      NA       NA    
I(X1 * X6)          NA         NA      NA       NA    
I(X2 * X3)   8.612e-06  7.877e-05   0.109  0.91300    
I(X2 * X4)   9.445e-03  1.384e-02   0.682  0.49552    
I(X2 * X5)  -2.897e+00  4.374e+00  -0.662  0.50819    
I(X2 * X6)  -3.869e+00  5.762e+00  -0.671  0.50233    
I(X3 * X4)  -1.687e-03  3.852e-04  -4.378 1.54e-05 ***
I(X3 * X5)  -2.229e-01  4.396e-02  -5.072 6.08e-07 ***
I(X3 * X6)  -1.212e-02  2.702e-02  -0.449  0.65393    
I(X4 * X5)  -1.071e+02  2.150e+01  -4.981 9.49e-07 ***
I(X4 * X6)  -1.615e+01  3.119e+01  -0.518  0.60474    
I(X5 * X6)          NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.903 on 395 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6773,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6626 
F-statistic: 46.06 on 18 and 395 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16


Analysis of Variance Table

Response: Y
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)    
X1           1    585     585   9.3699 0.0023565 ** 
X2           1   3441    3441  55.0854 7.148e-13 ***
X3           1  34857   34857 558.0314 < 2.2e-16 ***
X4           1   3576    3576  57.2444 2.733e-13 ***
X5           1   2065    2065  33.0577 1.793e-08 ***
X6           1      5       5   0.0821 0.7745688    
I(X1 * X2)   1    217     217   3.4746 0.0630583 .  
I(X1 * X3)   1      0       0   0.0016 0.9680901    
I(X1 * X4)   1      4       4   0.0704 0.7908357    
I(X2 * X3)   1    801     801  12.8267 0.0003843 ***
I(X2 * X4)   1     94      94   1.5072 0.2202955    
I(X2 * X5)   1      1       1   0.0101 0.9198052    
I(X2 * X6)   1      1       1   0.0085 0.9265045    
I(X3 * X4)   1   3805    3805  60.9172 5.390e-14 ***
I(X3 * X5)   1    481     481   7.6932 0.0058058 ** 
I(X3 * X6)   1    297     297   4.7533 0.0298321 *  
I(X4 * X5)   1   1542    1542  24.6828 1.008e-06 ***
I(X4 * X6)   1     17      17   0.2683 0.6047441    
Residuals  395  24673      62                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

[dput(head(assignment.data, 10))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fujma.png)

Thank you very much for anyone that solve my problem.

Original Post:[R-3 not defined because of singularities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665127/r-3-not-defined-because-of-singularities)

```
dput(head(assignment.data, 10))
Output:
structure(list(X1 = c(2012.917, 2012.917, 2013.583, 2013.5, 2012.833, 
2012.667, 2012.667, 2013.417, 2013.5, 2013.417), X2 = c(32, 19.5, 
13.3, 13.3, 5, 7.1, 34.5, 20.3, 31.7, 17.9), X3 = c(84.87882, 
306.5947, 561.9845, 561.9845, 390.5684, 2175.03, 623.4731, 287.6025, 
5512.038, 1783.18), X4 = c(10L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 
3L), X5 = c(24.98298, 24.98034, 24.98746, 24.98746, 24.97937, 
24.96305, 24.97933, 24.98042, 24.95095, 24.96731), X6 = c(121.54024, 
121.53951, 121.54391, 121.54391, 121.54245, 121.51254, 121.53642, 
121.54228, 121.48458, 121.51486), Y = c(37.9, 42.2, 47.3, 54.8, 
43.1, 32.1, 40.3, 46.7, 18.8, 22.1)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @RonakShah here is the dput

Comment: What are you actually asking for? Why you get NA's ?

Comment: @Sirius, yes, Im asking why am I get NA and how to solve this problem

Comment: What actually is the problem, beyond understanding the NAs? Performing linear regression with interaction terms?

Answer (score 0):

You only gave us 10 rows of data, so this answer is guesswork, but seeing how its the X5 and X6 terms that are missing parameters the answer to the NA's is this:

You have too few independent data rows to fit that many parameters. You need at the very least one data row for each parameter.

Furthermore, based on your formula I am guessing you mean to include all second degree interactions in the data. To that effect the formula should have been:

```
Multi.interact.reg<-lm(Y~X1*X2+X1*X3+X1*X4+X1*X5+X1*X6+X2*X3+X2*X4+X2*X5+X2*X6+X3*X4+X3*X5+X3*X6+X4*X5+X4*X6+X5*X6,data = assignment.data)
```

Or easier:

```
Multi.interact.reg< lm( Y ~ (X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6) * (X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6) , data = assignment.data )
```

Or even shorter:

```
Multi.interact.reg <- lm( Y ~ .*. , data=assignment.data )
```

Note the following, in a formula `X1*X2` is equivalent to `X1 + X2 + X1:X2` where `X1:X2` is the interaction term between X1 and X2.

On the topic of `X1*X2`, `X1:X2` and `I(X1*X2)`:

Try this:

```r
# add a variable X1mX2 that is X1 multiplied by X2
assignment.data$X1mX2 <-
    assignment.data$X1 * assignment.data$X2

# try these three models:
lm( Y ~ I(X1*X2), data=assignment.data )
lm( Y ~ X1mX2 , data=assignment.data )
lm( Y ~ X1:X2 , data=assignment.data )
```

They all give the *same* result. `X1:X2` is arguably better to write than `I(X1*X2)` but achieve the same outcome here. (That being said, it's good to know about the `I(...)` syntax for things like quadratic terms like I(X^2))

Nevertheless. Your NA's are due to not having enough independent data to fit more coefficients.

But what *is* your problem here? The last thing I would want to do, is to do your homework for you.

**EDIT**: A demonstration on how your forumla can perfectly well work for 414 data records.

Here is some randomly generated data with 414 rows and your 6 X variables and a Y:

```r
ncol <- 7
nrow <- 414

## random assignment data with 414 rows:
assignment.data <-
    matrix( rnorm( nrow*ncol ), nrow=nrow ) %>%
    as.data.frame %>%
    setNames( c( "Y", paste0( "X",1:6) ))

Multi.interact.reg <- lm( Y ~ .*. , data=assignment.data )
summary(Multi.interact.reg)
```

The summary of it looks like this:

```
> summary(Multi.interact.reg)

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ . * ., data = assignment.data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.1748 -0.6586  0.0088  0.6075  3.4569 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.007730   0.048957   0.158   0.8746  
X1          -0.020282   0.050103  -0.405   0.6858  
X2          -0.027244   0.046135  -0.591   0.5552  
X3          -0.033377   0.051385  -0.650   0.5164  
X4           0.058613   0.053728   1.091   0.2760  
X5           0.001110   0.047508   0.023   0.9814  
X6          -0.033624   0.050272  -0.669   0.5040  
X1:X2        0.062613   0.051556   1.214   0.2253  
X1:X3       -0.108269   0.051451  -2.104   0.0360 *
X1:X4       -0.106597   0.053761  -1.983   0.0481 *
X1:X5       -0.012042   0.051551  -0.234   0.8154  
X1:X6       -0.036547   0.049531  -0.738   0.4610  
X2:X3        0.083803   0.045765   1.831   0.0678 .
X2:X4       -0.024941   0.050207  -0.497   0.6196  
X2:X5        0.047340   0.041194   1.149   0.2512  
X2:X6       -0.075696   0.048885  -1.548   0.1223  
X3:X4       -0.018825   0.057152  -0.329   0.7420  
X3:X5       -0.024407   0.052880  -0.462   0.6447  
X3:X6       -0.110122   0.056965  -1.933   0.0539 .
X4:X5        0.023246   0.056187   0.414   0.6793  
X4:X6       -0.009225   0.050770  -0.182   0.8559  
X5:X6        0.016736   0.048907   0.342   0.7324  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.976 on 392 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.05964,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.009264 
F-statistic: 1.184 on 21 and 392 DF,  p-value: 0.2611
```

Again - it's not the method you use that is the problem, it's the data you are working with.

Comment: so what is the different between I(X1*X2) and X1*X2, this I(X1*X2) method is taught by my lecturer and I just follow her

Comment: still have NA while using
```Multi.interact.reg<-lm(Y~X1*X2+X1*X3+X1*X4+X1*X5+X1*X6+X2*X3+X2*X4+X2*X5+X2*X6+X3*X4+X3*X5+X3*X6+X4*X5+X4*X6+X5*X6,data = assignment.data)```

Comment: i have total 414 observation

Comment: I knew that it is my homework. sorry about that. I just have doubt to solve the NA problem. I have searched for some post but I still can't clear my doubt so that I posted my doubt here. Sorry for inconvenient cause.

Comment: So if there are three NAs, can I just not incl these 3 interaction terms in my Y(hat) equation??

Comment: Not really. You should set up the equation based on the problem you mean to solve. Not based on what seems to give results you like or not.

Comment: i see. then what method i can use to get rid of the NAs??the way you provide give same results

Comment: You are misunderstanding entirely. The problem is not the method, the problem is the data. Until you show the real data, we cannot tell you what is wrong with it.

Comment: here is the data
https://www.kaggle.com/quantbruce/real-estate-price-prediction

Comment: I had to register to download it, don't want to do that just for this.

Comment: here is the data https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vMp4U8TpOjd2sbFyiF2UO3RP6iRlVwEL/view?usp=sharing